# Can I create a hook for sqs queue creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, masstransit

We are trying to set alerts on SQS queues created by MassTransit and I was looking for a way to create a hook so that any time AWS SQS queue is created, we can create alerts for the queue or some notification that a queue has been created.

Is there an easy way to do it in MassTransit? Or through AWS?

I did research in Cloud watch options and did not find a way to monitor whether new queues were added or filtering based on specific pattern that would allow alert creation from that angle. So my hopes are on finding implementation from code side.

Any ideas will be very appreciated!

Comment: U sure a new queue is created or a new message? This seems extremely illogical to create a queue for each new message. What u can do is run a cron that fetches the list of queues u have and alert u when it changes - bad architecture if u ask me.

Comment: We create new queue for new consumer. Consumer does not send messages, it processes messages that it gets from the queue. Now, the issue is that AWS SQS does not allow you to easily get notified if new queue was created and that is the issue we are trying to solve

Comment: I am not a dotnet person, but I would think MassTransit have hooks for each operation it does. Or call a user action (webhook, user function etc)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to use AWS step functions state machine have a lambda function be triggered to create a new SQS queue then pass the success state to another step in the state machine that contains a data payload with the result of the operation successfully creating the queue this step will then pass the successful operation result into the body of an SES or SNS message triggered by another lambda function. To be clear you have a state machine with two steps, step one create queue, step two dispatch alert on queue creation.